# how can i call javascript function in ListView Command Extensions

Tags: sharepoint-online

[image]

this is my javascript code i'm importing
"import * as Func from './ShortLink.js';"  but it gives error "Could not find a declaration file for module './ShortLink.js'. 'f:/Listview prac/src/extensions/listviewCmd/ShortLink.js' implicitly has an 'any' type."

Comment: is there any specific reason to use js file in SPFx? can't use convert code of js file to typescript?

Comment: Use SPComponentLoader for loading the files. Also, it is better to use Typescript code instead of JavaScript code in SPFx. check this if it helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/add-jqueryui-accordion-to-web-part

Comment: ya i can use or else how can i wrote this logic in that ts file?

Comment: i also want to import yourls-api in my code and i also installed npm i yourls-api but  i can't import it .... it's showing module not found